# Native Nginx reverse proxy to Docker container with Letsencrypt

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt, proxypass

I have an ubuntu 18.0.4 lts box with nginx installed and configuered as a reverse proxy:

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;

        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;

}
```

I have a website running in a docker container listening on port 3000. With this configuration if I browse to http://example.com I see the site.

I've then installed LetsEncypt using the standard install from their website then I run `sudo certbot --nginx` and follow the instructions to enable https for mydomain.com.

Now my `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` looks like this and i'm unable to load the site on both https://example.com and http://example.com:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;

        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;

   }



listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any logs in `/var/log/nginx/` directory?

Comment: access.log and error.log are empty (i cleared them after installing lets encrypt)

Comment: Have you tried `https://example.com` as it seems there is no automatic redirect from port 80 (http) -> 443 (https)

Comment: @Bernhard yes, i've updated my question. After running certbot i can't access the site on either http or https

Comment: can you run `nginx -t` from root user?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The problem wasn't with my nginx/letsencrypt config it was a networking issue at the provider level (azure).

I noticed the Network Security Group only allowed traffic on port 80. The solution was to add a rule for 443.

After adding this rule everything now works as expected.